# How can i use both integrated and Dedicated graphic card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

Hi so im kinda newbie in linux-gnu world my question is how can i use my both graphic cards ? like for example in windows by default it uses integrated graphic card for non heavy task in order to save power consumption, but if you run any heavy app/games that depend on the graphics it switch's automatically to the dedicated graphic card so you can have best performance,
i wonder if this is also possible in ubuntu ?
and the sad part is even if you want to switch between your graphic cards you have to restart your laptop/computer everytime you switch between from integrated to dedicated or vice versa.
thanks in advance!

p.s : im using intel and nvidia graphic cards

Comment: A combo of latest (or about) Nvidia drivers and newer kernels allows on demand usage like in Windows but it's still flaky.

Answer (score 0):

nVidia x server settings has that option:

[image]

Besides that you have in settings, power options: on demand, performance, and power saver if you do not want the nVidia tool.

Neither of these require a reboot.

Comment: it still requires to restart the laptop everytime i change the modes,
and the nvidia on-demand  mode is not giving me good performance when running a task that demand heavy graphic
the performance mode is still better but unfortunately it consumes lots of power,
i just wonder if its possible to use both graphics just like windows
integrated for low demand graphic apps (web browsing,music,etc...)
and dedicated for high demand graphic apps/games
or at least if thats not possible then is there anyway to change the modes without having to restart the laptop ?